# How to show hidden content inside a modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've created a modal, which contains an `open` button(inside the modal) to display 'other content' inside the modal itself. Here is the [jsfiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/do36uyp7/2/) link. The 'other content' is the `stacked navbar` ([jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/do36uyp7/) link for the reference).

I want that when I click on the `Open` button inside the modal, it should then display the stacked navbar. How can I connect the two jsfiddle links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with modals. Use **[Boostrap's collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)** function, or just write some simple jQuery using `slideToggle()`:

```
$('#toggler').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').find('.content').slideToggle();
    $('#myModal').find('.btn-text').toggle();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/do36uyp7/3/)**

I've created two content wrappers and two button text wrappers, the second of each being hidden on load. They're being toggled with and without animation, respectively.